# Resat function doesnt work im my dart code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-apps-script

I have a function in a main.dart file called resat() and the problem is that its variables give an error 'The value of the local variable 'questionId' isn't used.
Try removing the variable or using it.' and I don't understand why. And also when you start the application, the button does not work, it should reset and restart the quiz

> ```
>  var totalScore= 0;
>  var questionId = 0;
> ```

here is my code in two files

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  var questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'Як тебе звати ?',
      'questionAnswer': [
        {'ansText': 'Надійка', 'score': 5},
        {'ansText': 'Ліза', 'score': 9},
        {'ansText': 'Маринка', 'score': 4}
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Який твій улюблений колір?',
      'questionAnswer': [
        {'ansText': 'Синій', 'score': 7},
        {'ansText': 'Зелений', 'score': 3},
        {'ansText': 'Жовтий', 'score': 8},
        {'ansText': 'Рожевий', 'score': 1}
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Яка у тебе стать ?',
      'questionAnswer': [
        {'ansText': 'Жіноча', 'score': 5},
        {'ansText': 'Чоловіча', 'score': 3}
      ]
    },
  ];

  var totalScore = 0;
  var questionId = 0;

  void _resat() {
    setState(() {
      var totalScore = 0;
      var questionId = 0;
    });
  }

  void changeVaprosik(int score) {
    totalScore = totalScore + score;
    setState(() {
      questionId = questionId + 1;
    });
    if (questionId < questions.length) {
      print('object');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('No Money'),
      ),
      body: questionId < questions.length
          ? MainContainer(
              questions: questions,
              changeVaprosiky: changeVaprosik,
              questionId: questionId)
          : Result(totalScore, _resat),
    );
  }
}

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  final int resultScore;
  final VoidCallback resat;
  Result(this.resultScore, this.resat);

  String get youGetIt {
    String resultText = '';
    if (resultScore <= 1) {
      resultText = 'loser';
    } else if (resultScore <= 15) {
      resultText = 'okay';
    }

    return resultText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(youGetIt),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        TextButton(onPressed: resat, child: Text('Restart'))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new variables, which it will be

```dart
 void _resat() {
    setState(() {
      totalScore = 0;
      questionId = 0;
    });
  }
```